# What's the difference between judging God and questioning God?

Tags: sin, doubt

In my answer to [Can man judge whether God is fair?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2170/36), I gave an example of the prophet Habakkuk questioning God in a judgmental way. God dealt with Habakkuk patiently, answering his questions.

On the other hand, as that question points out, there are people who judge God by deciding He is not fair that therefore should not be worshipped or trusted.

How do you draw the line between judging and questioning God?  Is it ok to question God, but not to judge Him?

Comment: Judging is a necessary part of being human. It is impossible to think about the actions of a person without judging those actions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. In questioning God, we are admitting that his knowledge and wisdom is superior to ours:

> “Why are you doing this?”
>
> “This doesn’t make sense to me.”
>
> “When will you rescue me from this situation?”

Whereas to judge him would be to assume that our knowledge and wisdom is superior:

> “You are wrong to do this.”
>
> “You’ve forgotten about ....”

It's a very thin line, but there is a line.

Comment: The line between the behaviors, and even the questions, are very thin. The line between the motives is miles wide!