# No matter how badly a person sins, are they always forgiven?

Tags: forgiveness

so I've had to talk to this religous leader at a mosque about christianity because my parents want for me to convert back to islam, anyways he asked me this. You believe that no matter what a person does God will always forgive them? and what about the victim of their sin, what happens to them?

Comment: So this is really two questions, both of which have been asked before: [Can I just sin my whole life and in the end receive forgiveness and go to heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4395/6071) and [Is the God of Christianity a just God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2302/6071).

Comment: You might find this website useful: http://www.answering-islam.org/ It addresses many topics that aren't appropriate for this Q&A site.

Comment: See [Ez 18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ez+18&version=NASB).

Comment: Everything except blasphamy of the Holy Spirit: *Therefore I say to you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven men. Anyone who speaks a word against the Son of Man, it will be forgiven him; but whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit, it will not be forgiven him, either in this age or in the age to come* (Matthew 12:31-32).  See also  (Mark 3:28-30) and  (Luke 12:10)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in your header, "No matter how badly a person sins, are they always forgiven?" as written, is "not necessarily". Jesus teaches in Mark 3:28-29 that all sins can be forgiven, except blasphemy of the Holy Spirit, but according to 1 John 1:5-9, Jesus blood cleanses us from all sin (v. 7b), but verse 9 makes it clear that confession is an essential and required antecedent of forgiveness. This is also demonstrated in Jesus teachings in Luke 18:10-14, where the tax collector made a confession of his sin, but the Pharisee did not, and Jesus praised the tax collector, and held the Pharisee in low regard. 
So, if you confess your sins, they will be forgiven.

As far as a person's victims, Christianity does not have as clear a statement on this. In Christianity, the teachings on the question of forgiveness of sin mostly relate to the sin against God, and not to the aspects of sins against our neighbors. But Jesus' teaching in Matthew (5:23-24) guides us that if we sin and harm our neighbor, that we should make matters right with him, before making our confession.